# Not being able to show the notifications using snackbar. Is there a good way to notify the user? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why would this not work in flutter. The Snackbar is not getting displayed. Is there a another way to this?
I just want to show the notification.

There is no error in the console though.

Also, I want the notifications to be displayed on any page I am currently. Can somebody help me achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
class _KudaBinState extends State<KudaBin> {
  final _model = MainModel();
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(notification["title"] + " " + notification["body"])));
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        final notification = message['data'];
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
      model: _model,
      child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: Color(0xffe46b10),
            accentColor: Color(0xff0f03fc),
            textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
          ),
          home: ScopedModelDescendant(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget, MainModel model) {
            return _model.isAuthenticated
                ? Requests(_model)
                : FutureBuilder(
                    future: _model.autoAuthenticate(),
                    builder: (context, authResultSnapShot) {
                      return authResultSnapShot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : WelcomePage(_model);
                    },
                  );
          }),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT - It doesn't have to be snackbar. But as per my current code, is there a way to notify the user across all the pages?

Comment: Firebase Messaging does not show notifications when application is open. you need to implement your local notifications when ```onMessage``` triggers.

Comment: does it log the message?

Comment: @JagrajSingh can you tell me some way to trigger local notifications?

Comment: @neuromancer What logs are you talking about?

Comment: print("onMessage: $message"); does this statement print?

Comment: @neuromancer yes, it does. I am able to receive the notifications. I just need a proper way to notify ht users. I tried using Snackbar but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin for local notifications,
First, initialize the `flutter_local_notification` plugin before `FirebaseMessaging` plugin and then in `onMessage` use flutter local notification to show a notification.
You can change the styling and other stuff in notifications.

Example:

```
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(    
          1,notification,'subtitle',secondNotificationPlatformSpecifics);
      },
```

Note: The above code is just an example of how you can use flutter_local_notification in firebase messaging configuration to show the notification. For full example refer [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

About Snackbar:
You need a Scaffold widget to show snackbar. If you don't want to use one then you can use
[GetX plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Example:

```
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        Get.snackbar('Hi',message);
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `Scaffold` widget, add a Scaffold widget, Set a `GlobalKey()` for the scaffold.

```
//inside a state of a widget
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

build(context){
      return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: //...,
      );
    }
```

and show the SnackBar like this

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(//..your snackbar widget)
```

Comment: SplashScreen and Welcome Page have the scaffold widgets. and I don't want to bring it in the material app as there are a number of pages in my project and creating a global key for every scafold is not feasible in my project. I just want to notify the users.

Comment: Only the almighty Scaffold can only show the SnackBar, otherwise use FlushBar from pub.dev

Comment: are you using multiple MaterialApp by any chance?

Comment: No multiple scaffold widgets

Comment: Multiple scaffold is okay, multiple materialApp?

Comment: there is just one material app